# How do i partition my hard drive?

Tags: partitioning

I installed ubuntu and erased windows data and didn't made partitions while installing ubuntu. I had 2 partitions in windows 7 and now i have just one 245gb partition. I need one partition which i can use seperatly.

How do i create partitions now?

Comment: If you installed OS then you should have noticed the step to edit disk partitions. What have you done ? installed them alongside ? Erased windows partition before ? Usually a partition 2g for swap , 50g for / and rest available space for /home is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have free space to create partition or want to resize existing? Ubuntu Live Cd can help you, boot from it, run `gparted` and you are able to do many things, all what you need with partitions. Live CD can be written to DVD, or USB by program `uunetbootin`. Gparted live cd is alternative, you can download it directly from `uunetbootin` and write to usb disk.

If you have free space where you want create partition, just install gparted and run it.

In gparted choose a disk to operate with. Choose partition to resize, change size and apply changes. Or choose free space, create partition, apply changes.

Comment: My whole HDD is in one partition. Of which 12 Gib is used and 224 is unsed.

Comment: installed GParted.

Comment: options:- Resize/Move and Unmount.

Comment: You can not resize partition from you boot. Need some other ubuntu with gparted to do everything. Make a bootable usb with gparted, boot from it and you will be able to unmount and resize. after resize - create new one as you wish

Comment: Do you have usb stick? Install unetbootin and by it make this usb bootable ubuntu. Thats easy, just try.